# Associate two activities with a service. Terminate the service if the application is put in the background

Tags: android, android-service

I have an activity A that starts a Music Service on a button click and optionally can start another activity B on another button click. I want the music to play in the background when the *application* is being used. When it is not being used (both Activity A and B are not visible) I would like the music to stop.

I've tried starting the service from Activity A on the button click using `startService(mMusicIntent)` and stopping in a similar way using `stopService(mMusicIntent)`. The music does, indeed, stay playing as I jump between A and B, however if I am in Activity B and I put the application into the background (Home or switch app) the background Music service still plays. I can only stop the service using the `onDestroy()` method in Activity A.

Is there a better way of doing this? I don't want to pass data between either activities and the service (it simply plays music) so I didn't feel that binding was appropriate. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Ensure you are calling `stopService(mMusicIntent)` at the good time for you, but it should stop the service whatever the call is from activity A or B (or C, D...) in the `onDestroy()` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this with a bound service. I still don't know if this is best way to do something like this but it has the desired effect.

Activity A binds to the MusicService on the button click. In the MusicService we set the bind to start playing the music. Activity A unbinds when either the button is reclicked or Activity A is stopped. Activity B binds onCreate() and unbinds when onStop(). For sure I could probably tweak the code so that the correct lifecycle pairs are selected but this works for my use case.